# Hadoop - Sorting in Reducer

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop

I have a map reduce code, in mapper i am doing some computation whereas in reducer I am applying the formula in order to get the result. My result is in IntDouble pair as key and Text as value format. I need to know that how can I sort the result of the reducer ?

Here is the sample output of reducer. I need to sort by keys. I implemented all of the code in the mapper, and it sorted it perfectly but unlike the reducer, the result is not sorted.

```
[1      0.5]    Mr. Nice Guy
[1      0.0]    Rush Hour
[1      0.3]    Twin Dragons
[1      0.6]    Snake in the Eagle's Shadow
[1      0.5]    Police Story
[1      0.5]    Armour of God 2: Operation Condor
[1      0.5]    Drunken Master
```

Expected Sorted List:

```
    [1      0.0]    Rush Hour
    [1      0.3]    Twin Dragons
    [1      0.5]    Mr. Nice Guy
    [1      0.5]    Police Story
    [1      0.5]    Armour of God 2: Operation Condor
    [1      0.5]    Drunken Master
    [1      0.6]    Snake in the Eagle's Shadow
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want the keys sorted?
I would define an object `IntDoublePair`, make it comparable, implement whichever comparison logic that suites me, then in the reducer i would instantiate a `List<IntDoublePair> myList` and while iterating the values of each key, i would add them to the `myList`.finaly sort the list.
You can also search 'secondary sort mapreduce'... maybe it would suit your purpose

Comment: After assigning the result in the ArrayList<IntDoublePair>, should I make a method in order to sort the list ? because the default Collections.sort method doesn't seems to be working for this kind of string.

Comment: once you define IntDoublePair implements Comparable<IntDoublePair> Collections.sort will apply for your object and will sort your list. here is an excellent tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: when i think about it again it won't help you... because the reducer already iterates on the values of the same key... sorry :/

Comment: what exactly is your scenario?  secondary sort could help but maybe there are easier work arounds.. like splitting the key, appending the y coordinate to each value with some delimiter. then in the reducer splitting by this delimiter. then what i suggested firstly would work

Comment: I have gone through the link http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/, but I am confused with the implementation that how do I sort the IntDoublePair. Because I need to compare both Int and Double from IntDoublePair object.